# Flyout Page with "split" FlyoutLayoutBehavior + Right-to-Left in Xamarin.Forms V5

Tags: xamarin.android

**Description**

I'm trying to apply RTL direction on the Flyout page with split behavior , it works correctly on IOS(master page on the right ) .But in the android It stays on the left side. Any ideas or could somebody help me with custom renderer?

I used Different solution without any result like below :

1- add android:supportsRtl="true" to AndroidManifest.xml

2- add FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft in the constructor of the Flyout page

3- add Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Rtl; in the MainActivity File

**Steps to Reproduce**

use Xamarin forms version 5

create flyout page and apply the above solutions

Deploy the app in android device or emulator

**Expected Behavior**
the master page should appear in the right side

**Actual Behavior**
the master page it is still appear in the left side

[FLayout RTL issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15359)

Answer (score 0):

To display the FlyoutPage on the right side, please set `FlowDirection` to `RightToLeft` for the flyoutPage.

So, you can add code `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` to your `FlyoutPage1.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="POCXamarinForm.FlyoutPage1"
             FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:POCXamarinForm">
  <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <pages:FlyoutPage1Flyout x:Name="FlyoutPage" />
  </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
  <FlyoutPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <pages:FlyoutPage1Detail />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

For more,you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left .

Comment: when  I add FlowDirection="RightToLeft" the master page still in the left and extra space appeared in the left area of master details page , please check this link https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/105156426/167399522-98385d23-247c-486d-9bd6-94d4ea38eddf.PNG

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem on android mobile .And the extra space  is transparent color in android mobile. In android tablet, the color is white.

Comment: Please can you send me a sample because I tried a lot of time without any result

Comment: I just  tested with your sample ,if you deploy to android mobile,  you'll notice that the space on the left has a different color. But I also find that the Page button is disappeared in  android tablet just as you posted  [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15359).

Comment: do you have any a  new idea? please or custom render

Comment: This should be an issue in android tablet, we have to wait patiently for the developer to deal with the issue. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

To display flyout page on right side, try adding the following code in the constructor of  FlyoutPage1.xaml.cs

```
this.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
Flyout.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
Detail.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvkqz.png)

Comment: the master page still in the left side  and extra space appeared in the left area of master details page , please check this link https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/105156426/167399522-98385d23-247c-486d-9bd6-94d4ea38eddf.PNG

Comment: android:supportsRtl="true"  is this added in android.manifest file?

Comment: yes I added android:supportsRtl="true" in android.manifest file and same issue

Comment: do you have any a  new idea please or custom renderer